# Access other functions inside the same function

Tags: javascript

there is some way to do this?

```
 function test()
    {

        this.write = function(text)
        {
            alert(text);
        }

        this.read = function()
        {
            this.write('foo');
            // WRONG WAY
            // test.write('foo');
        }
    }
```

How can i call the "this.write" function from "this.read"?

**EDIT:**

Found the awnser by EricG. Have tried with the code above and it works. But my real code still not working. I've to figure out what's happening.

The Way to call "THIS.WRITE" from inside "THIS.READ" is just by calling 'this.write()". Just like that.

Thanks!

Comment: How is `test` called in the first place? How is `read` called? That will determine what the value of `this` is in each. Why are you using `this`? Are you calling `test` as a constructor function? If so, why aren't you using the convention of starting the constructor function name with a capital (i.e. `function Test()`)?

Comment: use `this.write()` if you want to do `new test().read()`

Comment: holy mother... i try so many times to do this and was "this.foo()" to execute the other function. It's worked with that example but for some reason my code (other code that i don't put it in here) it's not working. Anyway. Thanks for help EicG and Quentin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function test()
{
    this.write = function(text)
    {
        alert(text);
    }

    this.read = function()
    {
        this.write('foo');
    }
}

var a = new test();
a.read();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pf5ZK/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function test()
{

    this.write = function(text)
    {
        alert(text);
    }

    this.read = function()
    {
        this.write('foo');
    }
}

var t = new test();
t.read();
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cQg6v/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function test()
{
   var self = this;

    this.write = function(text)
    {
        alert(text);
    };

    this.read = function()
    {
        self.write('foo');
    };

    // depending on browser versions or included libraries.
    this.another = function () {
        this.write('foo');
    }.bind(this);
}
```

You can also use this without the bind call, but under certain circumstances the meaning of 'this' may change.

Answer (score 0):

That totally depends on, where the function is called from.
I would suggest reading some more about the `this` keyword Maybe take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

If you create an Instance of `test`

```
function test()
{

    this.write = function(text)
    {
        alert(text);
    }

    this.read = function()
    {
        this.write('foo');
    }
}
var inst = new test()
inst.read() //foo
inst.read.call() //Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'write'
```

And call the method `read` of this instance, `this` will refer to the *well*,this instance of `test`

However if your code doesn't work, the method is probably called with another context.
Maybe an Eventlistener you added. And the callback function of it tries to call `this.write`
then `this` wouldn't refer anymore to the instance of test/your function.

What you could also do is preserving the context in a local variable like

```
function test()
{
    var context = this;
    this.write = function(text)
    {
        alert(text);
    }

    this.read = function()
    {
        context.write('foo');
    }
}
var inst = new test()
inst.read() // foo
inst.read.call() //foo
```

So as you see in the second case the `write` gets executed although `read` is called with the Global Object `Window` as its context.

Heres a [JSBin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)